# Boilerplate text not displaying in Oracle Forms 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

We're upgrading a large application from Forms 11g to 12c, and one of the few issues we've seen is that, on some forms (or some tabs within a form), boilerplate text and frame labels just don't appear when you run the form.

They are there in Form Builder, and have all relevant properties set correctly.  In the case of the frame labels, the frames show up, just without any text in them.  Also, although the frames have all properties set the same as other frames that do display correctly, the incorrect frames have square corners when they should be rounded.

There's only two things I can think of that might have some impact on this, but there's nothing I can do about either one at the moment:

- We're still using the 11g development tools (Form Builder) for the time being.  The OAS is 12c, and the forms get upgraded when compiled.
- So far, all of the text and frame labels that are not displaying are on canvases that are inherited into the form from a "template" form.

Any thoughts?  The missing text is all section headings, and the users would really like to have them back.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my coworkers is better at searching Oracle than I am, and found [Doc ID 2509488.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=211506222990043&id=2509488.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=b4wkdqa9h_93), which describes this bug in Forms 12c version 12.2.1.3.0 and later, and the patch to fix it, Patch 26932083.

Comment: Just to follow up, we have now implemented that patch, and after recompiling the affected forms, all is well.  Boilerplate text and frames are displaying as expected.